# Swift. Sound don't play for the second time

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I do a simple task from Udacity course ([Pitch Perfect](https://www.udacity.com/course/intro-to-ios-app-development-with-swift--ud585))

I have one screen where I record sound. After recording I save file  and pass it to the second screen.

On the second screen I have several buttons that play the sound differently. There I have a function that plays pitched sound.

The thing is, when I hit this function for the first time the sound plays, but for the second time there is no sound.

I'm stuck.

```
func playSoundWithPitchRate(pitch: Float) {

    self.audioPlayer.stop()
    self.audioEngine.stop()
    self.audioEngine.reset()

    let audioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    self.audioEngine.attachNode(audioPlayerNode)

    let changePitchEffect = AVAudioUnitTimePitch()
    changePitchEffect.pitch = pitch
    self.audioEngine.attachNode(changePitchEffect)

    self.audioEngine.connect(audioPlayerNode, to: changePitchEffect, format: nil)
    self.audioEngine.connect(changePitchEffect, to: self.audioEngine.outputNode, format: nil)

    let audioFileBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(PCMFormat: self.audioFile.processingFormat, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(self.audioFile.length) )

    do{
        try self.audioFile.readIntoBuffer(audioFileBuffer)
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print("self.audioFile.readIntoBuffer(audioFileBuffer)")
        print(err.localizedDescription)
    }

    audioPlayerNode.scheduleBuffer(audioFileBuffer, atTime: nil, options: .Interrupts) { () -> Void in

        // reminder: we're not on the main thread in here
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.stopPlayButton.enabled = false
            self.makeSoundEffectButtonsEnabled(true)
        }

    }

    do {
        try audioEngine.start()
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print("audioEngine.start()")
        print(err.localizedDescription)
    }

    audioPlayerNode.play()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I've read the doc and figured out that where your read file into buffer

```
self.audioFile.readIntoBuffer(audioFileBuffer)
```

the files frame position is advanced by the number of frames read.

So next time the were no frames to read. So I reset the frame position like this

```
self.audioFile.framePosition = 0
```

Hope this will help somebody.